# Reloading table view in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

I have a text box in my app with a button and a table view.Inside this table view i am creating image views which will display some images.Now when i enter a number say 5 in the text box and then click the button then 5 images are displayed on the table view out of which 4 images are in the first row .Now the problem comes if i enter number less than 5 say 3 then i have to get only 3 images in the table view but still i am getting 5 images and if i enter more than 5 then i am getting the desired number on the table view.My piece of code is:-

```
if([imageArray count] >0)
{
    [imageArray removeAllObjects];
}

int j = [text.text intValue];

for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
{
   [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]]];
}

[tableView reloadData];     

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 5;
   }
   // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,125)];

    if([imageArray count]>0)
    {

        imageView1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CARRY.png"];
        imageView1.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
        [imageView1 release];
    }
    if([imageArray count]>1)
    {

        UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,5,100,125)];
        imageView2.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:1];
        [imageView2 addSubview:button6];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
        [imageView2 release];
    }
    if([imageArray count]>2)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 5, 100, 125)];
        imageView3.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:2];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView3];
        [imageView3 release];
    }
    if([imageArray count]>3)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(460,5,100,125)];
        imageView4.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:3];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView4];
        [imageView4 release];
    }

}
else if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
    if([imageArray count]>4)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,125)];
        imageView5.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:4];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView5];
        [imageView5 release];
    }
    if([imageArray count]>5)
    {                           
        UIImageView *imageView6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,5,100,125)];
        imageView6.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:5];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView6];
        [imageView6 release];
    }

    if([imageArray count]>6)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView7= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 5, 100, 125)];
        imageView7.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:6];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView7];
        [imageView7 release];
    }
    if([imageArray count]>7)
    {                           
        UIImageView *imageView8 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(460,5,100,125)];
        imageView8.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:7];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView8];
        [imageView8 release];
    }
}

else if(indexPath.row == 2)
{
    if([imageArray count]>8)
    {
        UIImageView *imageView8 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,125)];
        imageView8.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:8];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView8];
        [imageView8 release];
    }
    if([imageArray count]>9)
    {                           
        UIImageView *imageView8 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,5,100,125)];
        imageView8.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:9];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView8];
        [imageView8 release];
    }                           

}




return cell;

}
```

I am clearing the array and again adding images to it then reloading the table view but why is the output then not coming according to the needs.Please help.

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: can you show us the tableViewDatasource method `numberOfRowsInSection` and the tableView's method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: see my edited ques ,,and help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the image views but you aren't removing the image views that you've added earlier in case of cell reuse.

Comment: now i added buttons in the table view and added images to it .but then also same answer i am getting

Comment: How does that make any difference? Buttons or Image views you are adding them but not removing them.

Comment: BTW Have you looked at [`AQGridView`](https://github.com/pjay/AQGridView)? It seems to have solved the same thing you're trying to solve.

Comment: @deepak,,please give the part of the code which i need to do please,here also i am removing the contents from the array then what i have to do ,sry i am a fresher

Comment: A close [`sample`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/ImageGrid.zip). Hope it helps you figure it out.

Comment: how can i add differetnt images to the next row

Comment: Maintain an `images` array. Replace `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"];` with `imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:((indexPath.row * 4) + i - 1)];`